# Deleting a leaf node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, function, class, recursion, binary-search-tree

In Binary Search Tree (BST), I am trying to delete a leaf node by the following method. However, though 'id' is same, it is not getting deleted.

Code -

```
class BSTNode:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value=value
        self.left=None
        self.right=None


def insert(self, new_value):
    if new_value<self.value:
        if self.left:
            self.left.insert(new_value)
        else:
            self.left=BSTNode(new_value)
    else:
        if self.right:
            self.right.insert(new_value)
        else:
            self.right=BSTNode(new_value)

def inorder(self):
    if self.left:
        self.left.inorder()        
    
    print(self.value, end=' ')
    
    if self.right:
        self.right.inorder()

def delete(self, value_to_delete):
    print('\n')
    print('self.value', self.value)
    print('self.left', self.left, 'left id', id(self.left))
    print('self.right', self.right, 'right id', id(self.right))
    
    if value_to_delete==self.value:
        print('self.value', self.value, 'self ', self, 'self id', id(self) )
        self=None
    elif value_to_delete<self.value:
        self.left.delete(value_to_delete)
    else:
        self.right.delete(value_to_delete)

bsttree=BSTNode(10)
bsttree.insert(5)
bsttree.insert(15)
print('Inorder')
bsttree.inorder()
bsttree.delete(5)
print('Inorder after deletion of leaf node 5')
bsttree.inorder()
```

**Code output**

```
Inorder
5 10 15 

self.value 10
self.left <__main__.BSTNode object at 0x7febad1585b0> left id 140650197910960
self.right <__main__.BSTNode object at 0x7febad04e880> right id 140650196822144


self.value 5
self.left None left id 4529773304
self.right None right id 4529773304
self.value 5 self  <__main__.BSTNode object at 0x7febad1585b0> self id 140650197910960
Inorder after deletion of leaf node 5
5 10 15
```

However, if I change the 'delete' function to below, the node gets deleted

```
def delete(self, value_to_delete):
    print('\n')
    print('self.value', self.value)
    print('self.left', self.left, 'left id', id(self.left))
    print('self.right', self.right, 'right id', id(self.right))
    
    if value_to_delete==self.value:
        print('self.value', self.value, 'self ', self, 'self id', id(self), )
        return None
    elif value_to_delete<self.value:
        self.left=self.left.delete(value_to_delete)
    else:
        self.right=self.right.delete(value_to_delete)
```

Do you know why it is deleting in the second case and not in the first?**

Comment: `self=None` does exactly nothing.  It's just rebinding a local variable; it doesn't affect anything in the caller or in the rest of the tree, because you're not modifying an object, just losing a local reference to it.  In the second case, you're actually modifying the `self.left` or `self.right` attributes of the object that `self` points to.

Answer (score 0):

The first form of your `delete` is a no-operation. The `self` name inside it is just a local variable, and changing it to `None` will not affect any reference to it on the parent node.

The second form updates the reference on the parent node itself, with the returned value. It is *also* broken, because intermediate nodes also return None (it is an implicit return, since you don't write a `return` statement) - therefore, grand-parent nodes will delete the parent nodes, all the way down. The code, as is, will just work in a tree of height 2.

Something along this will fix most of the issues (although I am not checking for further corner cases):

```py
def delete(self, value_to_delete):
    ...
    if value_to_delete==self.value:
        print('self.value', self.value, 'self ', self, 'self id', id(self), )
        return None
    elif value_to_delete<self.value:
        self.left=self.left.delete(value_to_delete)
    else:
        self.right=self.right.delete(value_to_delete)
    return self
```